# Python Check if at least 1 item in a 2d list is None

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider some 2d lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,None]]

b = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8]]
```

How to check if there is at least one **None** in a 2d list?

Outputs:
deal with a should output a bool value **False**, and b should output **True**.

I have no ideas when the list be a 2d list.

Comment: *"I have no ideas when the list be a 2d list."* Does that mean the list may be 1D sometimes, and 2D other times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two loops, one inside the other.

```
def at_least_one_none(array):
    for row in array:
        for item in row:
            if item == None:
                return True
    return False
```

This can be simplified by using `None in row` rather than the inner loop.

```
def at_least_one_none(array):
    for row in array:
        if None in row:
            return True
    return False
```

Either could be written using `any()` with a generator expression:

```
def at_least_one_none(array):
    return any(None in row for row in array)
```

And at that point you barely need the function.

Answer (score 1):

This function returns `True` if the a 2nd list contains at least one `None`, otherwise it returns `False`

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,None]]

b = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8]]
     
     
def fun(a_list):
    for l in a_list:
        if None in l:
            return True
    return False
    
print(fun(a))
print(fun(b))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Don't use the name of built-ins like `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you first merging all the lists into one, and then checking that value is `None` or not individually, and returning `[True, True,..False]`. Lastly check if there is any True in it.

Code:

```
True in [i==None for i in sum(<YourList>,[])] #returning True with None
```

Or filter out None from list and then check if it still the same size

```
list(filter(None, sum(<Yourlist>,[])))!=len(<Yourlist>) #returning False with None
```

Comment: The question isn't about Pandas.